# mysql and asp.net connectivity

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql

I'm trying to developing asp.net web sites.according to requirement i have to get some
data from my sql db and update in to ms sql server.

I want to get some updated information from my sql db. How can i track the updated field 
or id in my sql db using asp.net.

Need web services or any technologies? Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Updated the response. Not sure if you are notified if I change my reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like a background job that does not needs a lot of user interaction. Here is something I would suggest:

1. In your MySQL database, have UpdatedDate field and make sure that is updated everytime data is changed.
2. Create a SSIS package that checks in required tables for the rows updated today and insert/update that in to SQL database.
3. Create a job in SQL and use it to configure SSIS package execution for each day.

Update: You can create the package in SQL database. In the package, your source will be MySQL database and sink will be the SQL database.

Comment: Thanks danish.Can we create SSIS package using my sql db?